# How to delete metrics in opentsdb using http api

Tags: opentsdb

How to delete metrics in Opentsdb using HTTP API based on given time period.

http query and metric name

Comment: ```tsdb scan 2014/05/01 sum tag_name1=tag_value1 tag_name1=tag_value1 --delete```

Answer (score 4):

edit /etc/opentsdb/opentsdb.conf file
add below property to enable deletion
tsd.http.query.allow_delete=true

then restart opentsdb.

try below sample query to delete data ,
select http DELETE method in rest client.

http://host:4242/api/query?start=2016/02/16-00:00:00&end=2016/02/17-23:59:59&m=avg:1m-avg:metricname